# Why didn't God call the unrighteous dead to life up to Jesus crucifixion

Tags: life-of-jesus, crucifixion

After Jesus died on the cross at Calvary, many of the saints who were dead rose from the dead and appeared To many in Jerusalem. Since a resurrection involving a huge number of people such as this has never happened since the beginning, the unrighteous dead up to this point were not called back to life.

*Mathew 27:52-53*

> and the graves were opened; and many bodies of the saints which slept arose, and came out of the graves after his resurrection, and went into the holy city, and appeared unto many.

The book of Revelation speaks of a paired form of resurrection where the righteous dead are brought to life first and then the unrighteous dead second.

Why didn't this happen in the resurrection that happened when he died on the cross?

Comment: This Question should be of help: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/95953/was-the-resurrection-part-and-parcel-of-jesus-salvific-mission

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan. Thanks for the link

Comment: There would be no reason to recall the unrighteous from hades while still the heavens and earth stand. Only when these are disposed of, would there be any righteous reason, or need, to recall them to judgment. Gehenna, the lake of fire, is not yet kindled, ready to receive them, body and soul. But views about these matters differ so you would need to scope this question or there will be various answers from different directions.

Comment: @NigelJ, I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be no reason to recall the unrighteous from hades while still the heavens and earth stand. Only when these are disposed of, would there be any righteous reason, or need, to recall them to judgment. Gehenna, the lake of fire, is not yet kindled, ready to receive them, body and soul.

Comment: But is that equal, light for darkness, righteous for the unrighteous. God designed the universe in binary

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel That is not my own understanding. God is good, sheer goodness. He made light to shine in a darkness that was not his own creation. But I would not wish to further argue the point. All my books are on my website, freely available. My profile has the details.

Answer (score 1):

No wicked person has been, or ever will be resurrected until after the Millennium of Peace has ended. None can abide on this Earth in the presence of the Savior, or be embodied again until after this period of peace, rest and glory, commenced with the marriage of the Lamb, has ended.
John the Beloved says so in His testimony in Revelation 20:5-6:

> But the rest of the dead lived not again until the thousand years were finished. This is the first resurrection. Blessed and holy is he that hath part in the first resurrection: on such the second death hath no power, but they shall be priests of God and of Christ, and shall reign with him a thousand years.